# Execute WMIC command in nested for-loop

Tags: batch-file, wmic

this is my first time creating a batch file and I'm relatively new to this coding language. I wish to create a batch file that scans through all DLL files within a folder to retrieve and write the version info into a new text file. The nested for-loop functioned well but I couldn't get the WMIC command to execute, can you help?

Upon double-clicking to run the batch file, this is what I will get:

```
    Description = Invalid query
    'WMIC DataFile Where "Name='mydirecotry\myfile.dll'" Get Version'
    Node - myPCname
```

Here are the codes I wrote:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

FOR %%I in (D:\mydirecotry\*.dll*) DO (

    SET Location='WMIC DataFile Where "Name='%%I'" Get Version'
    ECHO !Location!
    
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=" %%A In (!Location!) Do (      <---Where i think it went wrong
    
        For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%~A") Do Set "pver=%%B" 
        
        ECHO %%I - %pver% >> test.txt
    )
)
pause
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is with your WMIC command, more specifically the value of `Name` WMIC requires the backslashes in the names to be escaped with another. This means you're going to have to `Set "dll=%%A"` then use `"Name='!dll:\=\\!'"`. However it may be better if you got rid of all of that code and just used `WMIC /Output:"test.txt" DataFile Where "Drive='D:' And Path='\\mydirectory\\' And Extension='dll'" Get Name, Version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the majority of my earlier comment is already within a supplied answer, I have decided to provide the alternative method I used within that comment, as an answer.

For the task you've laid out in your question, you should be able to have a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), with no `set` or `for` commands, just containing:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" /Output:"test.txt" DataFile Where "Drive='D:' And Path='\\mydirecotry\\' And Extension='dll'" Get Name, Version
```

Answer (score 0):

The DLL version information collection task can be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(for %%I in ("D:\V4-x64\Exe\Bin\*.dll*") do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set "FileName=!FileName:\=\\!"
    for /F "skip=1" %%J In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where Name^="!FileName!" GET Version 2^>nul') do if defined FileName set "FileName=" & echo %%I - %%J
)) >test.txt
endlocal
```

Each backslash in full qualified file name must be escaped with one more backslash. That is a special **WMIC** requirement on using `DATAFILE` on which file name must be always specified with full path.

The command line specified within `'` is executed by **FOR** with running in background `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line in `'` appended as additional arguments. So executed is in background with Windows installed to `C:\Windows` the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where Name="D:\\V4-x64\\Exe\\Bin\\FileName.dll" GET Version 2>nul
```

The equal sign must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character and not as argument separator as otherwise `=` would be replaced by a space character before running `cmd.exe` in background which would make the arguments invalid for `wmic.exe`.

The redirection operator `>` must be escaped also with `^` to be interpreted as literal character on parsing the **FOR** command line before executing **FOR** at all.

**WMIC** outputs the data Unicode encoded with UTF-16 Little Endian encoding with byte order mark (BOM). **FOR** has problems to parse the Unicode output correct as expecting an ASCII/ANSI/OEM character encoding, i.e. one byte per character without null bytes. The byte sequence with the hexadecimal values `0D 00 0A 00` being UTF-16 LE encoded the line ending carriage return + line-feed is interpreted as `0D 0D 0A` by **FOR** (respectively `cmd.exe`). So there is an erroneous carriage return at end of the real line ending removed by **FOR** before processing further the remaining string.

For that reason the **WMIC** output is interpreted with skipping the first line containing just the string `Version` and so processed is first the second line with the version string by removing leading and trailing spaces.

The full qualified file name of the current DLL file and its version is output with command **ECHO**. Additionally the environment variable `FileName` is deleted to make sure that no further line output by **WMIC** including an empty line interpreted by **FOR** as a line with just a carriage return results in running once again command **ECHO** with loop variable `J` having assigned a carriage return.

The batch file does not work for DLL files with an exclamation mark in file name, but that should not matter here as I have never seen a DLL with `!` in file name.

Another solution provided by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) in a comment is much faster and works also for DLL file names with `!` in file name.

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE Where "Drive='D:' And Path='\\V4-x64\\Exe\\Bin\\' And Extension='dll'" GET Name,Version >"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +1 "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" >test.txt
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
```

**WMIC** searches itself for *.dll files in the directory `D:\V4-x64\Exe\Bin` and outputs full name of the DLL file and its version written into a temporary file being UTF-16 LE encoded with BOM. This temporary file is next processed with **MORE** with skipping the header line and the empty lines at bottom and the output is written into `test.txt` being a non-Unicode file. The temporary file is deleted finally.

For completeness:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE Where "Drive='D:' And Path='\\V4-x64\\Exe\\Bin\\' And Extension='dll'" GET Name,Version | %SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +1 >test.txt
```

This command line produces a non-Unicode encoded text file `test.txt` on which every line with a DLL file name and version is terminated with **two** carriage returns and one line-feed and with two empty lines at bottom with just one carriage return plus line-feed. So it is not recommended to use this single line variant.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~n0` ... file name of argument 0, i.e. the batch file name without file extension.
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `more /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic datafile /?`
- `wmic datafile get /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the operator `&` and the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both methods of Compo and yours and they worked equally well. Also, I appreciate the info you provided, it does give a much clearer pic of the batch script after experiencing it first hand.